# Unable to build and run react app using "npm run-script build serve -s build"

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my app react app to aws s3.

for some weird reason, when i run "npm start" vs "npm run-script build   serve -s build" it seems to change how I am making API calls to the backend.

I though it was easier to show you what is going on in a video so i made the video below
https://youtu.be/c9t3pMXyj5I

this is my setupProxy.js code::

```
//  setupProxy.js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        '/api',
        createProxyMiddleware({
             // works with npm start
              target:"http://127.0.0.1/",  
            // target: "http://qube-dev-env.eba-vriyszfz.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/",

            //  this never works, it should work with npm run build
            target: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}`,
            changeOrigin: true,
            onProxyReq: (proxyReq, req, res) => {
                console.log('Proxying Request to:', proxyReq._headers.host + proxyReq.path);
            },
        })
    );
};
```

this is the action that i am trying to run::

```
// works with npm start
// const baseUrl = `/api/user/`; 
// const baseUrl = "http://qube-dev-env.eba-vriyszfz.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/user"

const baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}api/user/`;   

export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const payload = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    console.log(`IM GOING TO PING:  ${baseUrl}login`);
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}login`, {

      // const response = await fetch(`login`, {
      // const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: payload,

    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      // If response status is not OK (e.g., 401 Unauthorized), throw an error
      const errorData = await response.json(); // Parse the error response
      throw new Error(errorData.error || 'Login failed');
    }

    const responseData = await response.json(); // Parse the successful response

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: responseData.token,
    });

    return { message: 'Login successful', color: 'green' };

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error.message);

    // Handle error, for example, dispatch Redux actions
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
      payload: error.message,
    });

    return { message: error.message, color: 'red', error: true };
  }
};
```

these are my scripts in package.json::

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Why is build the app for production changing so much about the API calls to the back end!

I didnt find any related problems to mine

what is going on!!!
any help is welcome!

UPDATE

so i was able to get the app to work with "npm run-script build serve -s build" when i tried to connect with my local server::

.env file::

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL="http://127.0.0.1/"
```

action::

```
// src/actions/authActions.js

export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCCESS';
export const LOGIN_FAILURE = 'LOGIN_FAILURE';
export const SIGNUP_SUCCESS = 'SIGNUP_SUCCESS';
export const SIGNUP_FAILURE = 'SIGNUP_FAILURE';
export const SET_TOKEN = 'SET_TOKEN';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';


// works with npm start
// const baseUrl = `/api/user/`; 

// works with npm build
const baseUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}api/user/`;   
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const payload = JSON.stringify({ email, password });
    console.log(`IM GOING TO PING:  ${baseUrl}login`);
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}login`, {

      // const response = await fetch(`login`, {
      // const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: payload,

    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      // If response status is not OK (e.g., 401 Unauthorized), throw an error
      const errorData = await response.json(); // Parse the error response
      throw new Error(errorData.error || 'Login failed');
    }

    const responseData = await response.json(); // Parse the successful response

    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: responseData.token,
    });

    return { message: 'Login successful', color: 'green' };

  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error.message);

    // Handle error, for example, dispatch Redux actions
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAILURE,
      payload: error.message,
    });

    return { message: error.message, color: 'red', error: true };
  }
};
```

Now am i getting this error on google chrome console::

```
IM GOING TO PING:  http://qube-dev-env.eba-vrudiyfz.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/user/login
:3000/:1 Access to fetch at 'http://qube-dev-env.eba-vriyszfz.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/user/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
authActions.js:20     POST http://qube-dev-env.eba-vriyszfz.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/user/login net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ authActions.js:20
f @ regeneratorRuntime.js:44
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:125
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:69
Oa @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
i @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
(anonymous) @ authActions.js:58
(anonymous) @ index.js:16
n.<computed> @ bindActionCreators.js:8
(anonymous) @ LoginForm.js:37
f @ regeneratorRuntime.js:44
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:125
(anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:69
Oa @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
i @ asyncToGenerator.js:22
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:27
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:19
(anonymous) @ LoginForm.js:34
Ie @ react-dom.production.min.js:54
Be @ react-dom.production.min.js:54
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:55
Dr @ react-dom.production.min.js:105
Fr @ react-dom.production.min.js:106
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:117
cs @ react-dom.production.min.js:274
je @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
Hr @ react-dom.production.min.js:109
qt @ react-dom.production.min.js:74
$t @ react-dom.production.min.js:73
authActions.js:48 error:  Failed to fetch
```